Nothing to do with books but everything to do with "BANGS"!
What two-word answer is depicted?




 This has something to do with a GRAND SLAM in tennis.

Why

 Top picture represents a podium (highlighting a gold medal in the Olympics I presume) which is hinting at sporting events and winning.

Following this lead

 The books contain the beginning letters of each of the four grand slam tournaments: AUSTRALIAN (open), FRENCH (open), WIMBLEDON and US (open).

The book orientations

 Further support this being the answer since the books that are open highlight the grand slams which end in ‘open’. Wimbledon doesn’t end in open and this is why it is represented by a closed book.

The title

 Represents the banging of tennis balls of course and thanks to Beastly Gerbil’s input Bang is a wordplay on ‘Grand Slam’.


I think the title is actually a pun on a 'grand slam' - as in a big slam would make a bang

Ah seems more plausible. I will wait for the op’s confirmation

This is the intended answer, but not G S's but just G S. The top image just represented a winner of all four (in the same year) - which is called a GS

The two-word phrase is

 Golden Slam

Which was achieved by

 Novak Djokovic this year by winning the Olympic tennis tournament

@PDT got it right with decoding the individual components - please upvote!

Damn I literally was about to ask about this

I was about to edit my answer ouch

@PDT You can certainly still edit this into your excellent answer as well!

Dw I will let you have it I was too slow and you beat me to it. Life sucks but hey well done

This is a great answer and makes sense but tbh I didn't even know there were something called [your answer]. The top image was just a representation of a "winner" so wasn't intended to be related to "top 3". +1 ofc!

@Prim3numbah That's wild - I feel like you (inadvertently) clued it perfectly for [my answer] and it would also have happened to be a timely puzzle, it being a rare occurrence that happened most recently in just the past few weeks!
